# IE9 Javascript onkeydown event changes the cursor position and doesn't permit to edit pasted data

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown

I have a problem of editing a pasted data in IE9 (IE only), when I try to separate by spaces the pasted string, the cursor runs at begin of the text or at the end. Then it adds the space or any another character I pressed. In case if I just enter a new value with spaces from a keyboard, no problem occurs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="direction">Your input here: </label><input name="direction" type="text" id="direction" size="55" maxlength="150" onkeydown="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" value="BIARRITZ1919PPDPTO903"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to add a "`javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase(); return true;`", but no success.